# Conditionally break debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am developing an application using C#. Here I put the example code for reference. I want to check functionality within for loop. I want to check in a particular point, here when `i > 250`. So I used `if` statement in several places and put the breakpoints inside it and debugging.

**Code:**

```
 1  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 2  {
 3      ...
 4      if (i > 250)
 5      {
 6          ...
 7      }
 8      ...
 9      if (i > 250)
10      {
11          ...
12      }
13      ...
14  }
```

Is there any other way to `conditionally break the debugging`?

*I am using VS2013*

Comment: Right click breakpoint, click `Condition...`

Comment: Can I set the expression like this `i > 250`?

Comment: Should work like that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the breakpoint, right-click the breakpoint. You'll get a menu with several options, including conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. create a break point, then right click the red dot and add a condition.

It will let you specify c# expressions the define the condition.